# Can a Jamaican citizen travel to Jamaica on an expired passport

Tags: passports, jamaica, jamaican-citizens

Hello there I plan on traveling to Jamaica next month for an emergency. My passport expires this month but I plan to renew my passport at the main pica location in Kingston. I have a valid permanent resident card and original birth certificate. Has anyone done this before, and on what airline? I’m scared because I don’t want to denied by the airline but they keep giving me generic responses for American Airlines.

Comment: For completeness, are you travelling from the US? Timatic (the system used by airlines https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/JM ) says “ Warning: if departing from the USA (regardless of any destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/or accepted departure document is required by the US immigration authorities.” Have you considered getting an Emergency Certificate https://congenjamaica-ny.org/emergency-certificates/?